# Firebase response is received after successful sign-in but token not saved in local storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've written a sign in method in Angular 6.0 as front-end and firebase as back-end. The sign in was successful as I could see it in the console, but the token was not auto saved in the browser's local-storage.

Below is my code. Do I explicitly need to write something?

Thanks in advance.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export class AuthService {  
    signupUser(email: string, password: string) {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .catch(
            error => console.log(error)
        )
    }

    signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .then(
            response => console.log(response)
        )
        .catch(
            error => console.log(error)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use localStorage.setItem('token','put response here') for storing token in browser's localStorage.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But can you help me out on why its not getting auto-saved? I heard angular has that feature to auto-save the token response in the local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: I was directly checking my [chrome > developer tools > Application > storage > localstorage] in my browser. But there is something called IndexedDB in the same above path which again has firebaseLocalStorageDB which saves the JWT received from the firebase.